# Would 3 hours be an ok transfer time from LGA to JFK for international flight?

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, short-connections, jfk, lga

My flight got changed and I now only have 3 hours (gate to gate) to get from LGA to JFK on Qatar Airways (going to Doha) on a Friday morning in May. The flight lands in LGA on Terminal B on Fri 8:05 am and leaves JFK at 11:15 am from Terminal 7. With all the constructions around LGA, would I have a decent chance of making my flight? I will not be checking bags.

Comment: Nope, will not check bag due to time constraints.  And my travel is end of may.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 3:10 is almost always sufficient.

Few points:

1. My first option would be Uber, then a Cab.  You can also pre-book a limo.
2. If you prefer a shared van, ask if you are at the last stop at LGA which is likely if you arrive at the Central Terminal.
3. If traffic on the Van Wyck is really backed up, you can get dropped off at the Air Train station in Jamaica and ride the train directly to JFK.
4. If traffic on the Grand Central or Queens in general is really, really backed up, you can get dropped at the Jackson Heights - Roosevelt Ave Subway and take the E train to Jamaica for the Air Train.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking a cab, there's no problem, three hours is plenty. As per this [flyertalk post](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/25930683-post7.html) it's a a ten minute walk from gate to the cab stand if you have no luggage. As per the [official page](http://laguardiaairport.com/getting-to-from/traveling-between-jfk-newark-airports/) you need at least 30 minutes to get from LGA to JFK. So you have close to two and half hours if using a cab at JFK which is enough even at JFK. Even with traffic jams, this is fine.

It's much hairier with a shuttle as you might need to wait for one and they always move slower. I would personally not risk it.

The gridlock is bad but with the taxi stand moved, it's better.

Comment: You are forgetting TSA lines; which can easily eat up 2 hours - and something one cannot avoid.

Comment: I didn't. That's why the shuttle is hairy.

Comment: Also don't forget it's insane rush hour time exactly when the OP lands...! It took me about 45min to get from JFK to LGA by shuttle and a taxi wouldn't have done any better since all the lanes are blocked equally...